# Acesso negado ao atualizar PIP

Tags: python, windows, pip

Estou executando o seguinte commando no prompt Windows

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

E estou recebendo um erro:

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado:
>   'd:\leonardo\python\django-treinaweb\env\scripts\pip.exe'

Lembrando que estou dentro de uma `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta executar o `cmd` como administrador.
Vai a `inicio/accesorios/Command Prompt` e da `clique direito/ executar como administrador.`

depois tenta o mesmo comando:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Deu certo. Mas acho que é porque eu estava dentro da virtualenv. As vezes tava apontando pra outro lugar, acha que pode ser isso?

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --upgrade pip --user
```

Vai dar certo.